# Advice: CustomWidget or adjust CSS? Surveyjs with Next.js, Material UI v5 (custom theme)

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, next.js, material-ui, surveyjs

I would appreciate some advice. This is the current situation:

- nextjs app with material ui v5 which uses a custom theme

  - this theme gets used in multiple apps, so the look and feel are always the same
- I want to build surveys forms via the creator and use all the available features

The survey components should look like the mui elements. I saw in the documentation that there are two possible ways:

- create a CustomWidget, which works nicely, e.g.:

```
    CustomWidgetCollection.Instance.add({
        name: 'mui-text-field',
        isFit: (question: QuestionTextModel) => question.getType() === 'text',
        render: (question: QuestionTextModel) => {
            return <FieldString question={question} />;
        },
    });
```

- or adjust the CSS of the theme

I did try both approaches – changing CSS and creating custom widgets – both seem to be an overwhelming amount of work.

I don't know what is the best approach. I thought it would be nice to use the components from mui, so my form would respect changes to the theme. But then I would need to rebuild a lot of functions in my CustomWidget. Textfields are straight forwards and not an issue, but radiogroups for example would be a bigger thing to tackle.
But on the other side reimplementing the CSS of mui, would also be a hustle since the structure of the HTML is probably different. (surveyjs and mui components are differently built I guess)

| CSS | custom widget |
| --- | --- |
| reimplement mui css | surveyjs functionality needs to be reimplemented |
| theme adjustments would need to be implemented twice | would take a lot of implementation testing time |

Does anyone has some experience or could give me his/her point of view?
Anything is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SurveyJS Creator v1.9.100 that has released this week has [the Theme Editor](https://surveyjs.io/stay-updated/release-notes/v1.9.100). You can [try it](https://surveyjs.io/create-free-survey). It allows visually to customize all SurveyJS css variables. Probably you will be able to get the needed result by using SurveyJS css variables only.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! This is nice if you want the users to adjust the theme (which I don't want). I also already use a `themeJson` in my setup.
But it does and certainly cannot support all Material UI offers. But from your answer, I understand that you are more leaning towards making the changes via CSS.

Comment: We want to make examples with some customized themes. We want to make an example with a theme that will be similar to material design. However, it will take a while.